# Why Doesn't My WebView App Prompt for Permissions?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-permissions

My Manifest is already set to request camera & mic permissions, the proof is that in "App Info" > "Permissions" there are the options to allow/deny mic and camera.

The issue is that the permission **prompt** in the app at **runtime** does not show up when I navigate my webView to a page that requests the mic / cam.

Here's the snippet of the webview meant to create the prompt:

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient(){
    override fun onPermissionRequest(request: PermissionRequest) {
        runOnUiThread {
            request.grant(request.resources)
        }
    }
}
```

If you'd like to see the complete activity: https://pastebin.com/93Uu9kYG

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes, it's in the paste bin @Ricardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle that as well by using `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` for more detail you can visit this doc: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting you can also achieve this by using a third-party library such https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: Thank you! I needed that as well as `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`

Comment: @PHP_gEeK Hey did you find the solution? I'm facing the same issue but nothing is working for me.